# equivalent for ifconfig dev 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, networking, bash, kvm-virtualization

When I need to create a temporary bridge with interface on Linux I would use the following:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig br0 192.168.10.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig br0 up
```

I have been updating my process to use the [ip](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) command, However, I do not find the equivalent for removing the IP stack (ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0) via the `ip` command

I have tried the following:

```
ip addr add 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
ip addr add 0.0.0.0/24 dev eth0
```

but it does not work to remove the existing `ip` on that device.

would anyone happen to know if this is possible with the `ip` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the old `ifconfig` command and its old Linux kernel API is limited to *one* IPv4 address per interface (and so interface aliases, which are really additional addresses rather than interfaces, are used to work around this limitation). This explains why to remove *the* IPv4 address, the method was to *set* it to (not really add) 0.0.0.0.

With *iproute2* tools, if you want to remove *any* address from an interface (always a good idea for a bridge port) without caring what address(es) are there, you can use `ip address flush`, which is a bulk removal command:

> [`ip address flush`](https://manpages.debian.org/ip-address.8.en.html#ip_address_flush_-_flush_protocol_addresses) - flush protocol addresses
>
> This command flushes the protocol addresses selected by some criteria.
>
> [...]
>
> Warning: This command and other flush commands are unforgiving. They
> will cruelly purge all the addresses.
>
> [...]

So in the end you can use:

```
ip address flush dev eth0
```

(you could add `-4` to limit the effect to IPv4).

---

There are other uses. For example this command:

```
  ip address flush to 10.1.0.0/16
```

would remove from any interface any address matching the block 10.1.0.0/16 *whatever its netmask*.

```
# ip -s -s address flush to 10.1.0.0/16
2: lxcbr0    inet 10.1.3.1/24 brd 10.1.3.255 scope global lxcbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
158: eth0    inet 10.1.1.1/8 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

*** Round 1, deleting 2 addresses ***
*** Flush is complete after 1 round ***
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for giving such a complete response

Answer (score 0):

You can't *delete* an IP address with the `add` command!

If you want to delete an IP address from an interface, you `del` it.

```
ip addr del 203.0.113.187 dev eth0
```